# Installing 16.04 on Lenovo Yoga 900 with nvme drive

Tags: boot, lenovo, nvme

I am attempting to install 16.04 on a new Lenovo Yoga 900. This type has an nvme drive and is set up by the BIOS as RAID, not AHCI (cannot be changed). I see multiple comments on the various forums that indicates that this should be possible.

However, when I boot from a USB drive, I cannot see the SSD at all. It does not mount, gparted does not see it, fdisk does not see it.

The BIOS sees it--I can boot into windows on that drive.

Kernel version is 4.4.0-21-generic. Gparted is 0.25.0.

Any pointers much appreciated.

--prasanna

Comment: (Linux Only) BIOS Update for Windows 10 (64-bit) - Yoga 900-13ISK2 http://support.lenovo.com/tw/zh/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/Yoga-Series/yoga-900-13isk2/downloads/DS119354

Answer (score 1):

At this point in time, it is not possible to install Linux on this machine. There is a very instructive thread on Lenovo's forum:

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Yoga-900-13ISK2-BIOS-update-for-setting-RAID-mode-for-missing/m-p/3339206/highlight/true#M7814

tl;dr: until Lenovo provides a BIO setup to disable the RAID, Linux cannot be installed. Lenovo said it might do it but no hard commitment.

Comment: Is there some way the Ubuntu community could write a driver to recognize this RAID mode on the Intel 82801 SATA Controller?  Seems like unless we unlock this issue ourselves, Lenova can just point the finger at Linux and say "We aren't blocking it from working as a hard drive; it works just fine for the Windows drivers"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as you said, Linux Kernel doesn't recognize NVME SSD drives on SATA Controller RAID mode. The solution is to change our BIOS settings to allow changing SATA Controller mode from RAID to AHCI.

Doing this means flashing BIOS to the specific version that allows us to do that. Also to be noted that when using AHCI mode we won't be able to run factory Windows installation. So if we install Ubuntu alongside Windows we will have to switch SATA mode every time we switch operating system.

Next solution is specific to Yoga 900-13ISK2, but if you have some other model version that has the same problem you'll have to adapt my answer searching for that specific model BIOS update for Linux only.

Here is what you have to do:

1. Download YOGA 900 BIOS update from [this URL](http://support.lenovo.com/ar/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/Yoga-Series/yoga-900-13isk2/downloads/DS119354).
2. Flash your BIOS executing the file you downloaded. It's possible that you might receive an alert sign saying the version of your BIOS is newer than the one you are trying to update. In this case follow point 3
3. (OPTIONAL) Flashing 'older' version of BIOS:

   1. **Enable "Bios Back Flash"** in the **"configuration"** BIOS setup menu or the downgrade will fail.
   2. Run downloaded `exe` file. It will start unpacking files to some temporal folder. Next, the alert message will appear. Ignore it, let that window live for a moment.
   3. Go to the folder `C:\Users\(YourUserNameFolder)\AppData\Local\Temp` and you will see a folder named something like `7zXXXXX.tmp`. Copy this temporal folder to some other place to keep it safe.
   4. You can close up now flashing BIOS window we ran earlier.
   5. Edit the copied temporal folder file platform.ini. Search for not commented [Bios_Version_Check], you will see on next line a flag value set to 1 or 2. Change this value to 0 and save (it will allow no version Bios check).
   6. Run this folder file runnable `exe`, probably named H2OFFT-W, you will see then version check will be skipped.
4. After BIOS update is complete, you'll have to enter BIOS setting. It will require you to power off your Yoga. While turned off, press (using a clip or something pointy) the button next to power button that has a curved arrow pointing down. This will power up your computer and show a list of options including entering BIOS setup.
5. Enter Bios Setup, go to Configuration and set SATA Controller mode to AHCI. Save and exit.

That will do it. Next time you run ubuntu installer it'll show SSD drive and all its partitions.

**NB**: the device will be called `/dev/nvme*`, *not* `/dev/sd*`.